# How to stop the timer in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to stop the timer?

All code with implementation is [available on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-trainin-2-gv9glh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

If you click on button 'Go', the timer will start. I want to pause or stop this time, but how?

Main function is:

```js
startTimerForSingleTraining(timer2) {
  console.log('timer 2', timer2)
  // if(timer2 === 'finished') {
  //   this.countDownForSingleStartTraining.unsubscribe();
  // } 
  this.countDownForSingleStartTraining = timer(0, this.tick)
    .subscribe(() => ++timer2.timer); 
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort of making a reproducible example, however it would be nice if you cut out unnescessary code so only the minimal code that reproduces the behavior is left. From seeing the function in your question, what keeps you from just unsubscribing `this.countDownForSingleStartTraining`?

Comment: Unsubscribing doesn’t work?

Comment: Work unsubscribe :)

Comment: Raz, sure works, but if you're not refresh the navigator, it's possible you're "listen" the observable before the change go on

Comment: How to to it ? @Eliseo

Comment: I want to say that, some times, in stackblitz you create an obsavable that you not unsubscribe. After, you cange the code to unsubscribe, but the observable before you change is still run. For this you give a "refresh" the "view of stackblitz". I went crazy sometimes that forget clear an interval in stackblitz. This was  the aim of my comment

Comment: If my answered worked for you can you also accept it please?:)

Answer (score 2):

Unsubscribe from the Observable:

`this.countDownForSingleStartTraining.unsubscribe()`